# json array needs to be formatted based text containing time in angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my angular js application, I have the following json array

```
 $scope.timeList =  [
      {
        "text": " 4:00 am",
        "value": "17"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:15 am",
        "value": "18"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:30 am",
        "value": "19"
      },
      {
        "text": " 3:45 pm",
        "value": "64"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:00 pm",
        "value": "65"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:15 pm",
        "value": "66"
      }
    ]
```

And I need to convert it into the following format :

```
 $scope.timeFormattedList =   [
      {
        "text": " 4:00 am",
        "unique" : "4.00",
        "value": "17"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:15 am",
        "unique" : "4.15",
        "value": "18"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:30 am",
        "unique" : "4.30",
        "value": "19"
      },
      {
        "text": " 3:45 pm",
        "unique" : "15.45",
        "value": "64"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:00 pm",
        "unique" : "16.00",
        "value": "65"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:15 pm",
        "unique" : "16.15",
        "value": "66"
      }
    ]
```

Here the new key "unique" is added to each json object based "text" key. If the "text" contains "pm" it should add 12 to it, otherwise same value remains.

Comment: `otherwise same value remains` - no it doesn't ... you have to drop the `am` and change the `:` to a `.` ... and then hire a coder to do the real work because this isn't hire a code monkey dot com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and to get unique value you can use [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with callback

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.timeList = [{
  "text": " 4:00 am",
  "value": "17"
}, {
  "text": " 4:15 am",
  "value": "18"
}, {
  "text": " 4:30 am",
  "value": "19"
}, {
  "text": " 3:45 pm",
  "value": "64"
}, {
  "text": " 4:00 pm",
  "value": "65"
}, {
  "text": " 4:15 pm",
  "value": "66"
}];

$scope.timeFormattedList = $scope.timeList.map(function (el) {
  var unique = el.text.trim().replace(/(\d+):(\d+)\s(\w{2})/, 
    function (match, hour, minutes, meridiem) {
      return (meridiem === 'pm' ? (+hour + 12) : hour) + '.' + minutes;
    });

  return {
    text: el.text,
    unique: unique,        
    value: el.value
  }
});

snippet.log(JSON.stringify($scope.timeFormattedList));
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$scope.timeFormattedList = $scope.timeList.map(function(item){
  var textArray = item.text.trim().split(" ");
  var timeArray = textArray[0].split(":");
  if(textArray[1] === "pm") {
    if(timeArray[0] != 12) {
      item.unique = parseInt(timeArray[0])+12+":"+timeArray[1];
    } else {
      item.unique = textArray[0]; 
    }
  } else {
    if(timeArray[0] != 12) {
      item.unique = textArray[0];
    } else {
      item.unique = "00:"+timeArray[1]; 
    }
  }
  return item;
});
```

Added specific handling for 12 am and 12 pm timings.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `map()` method.

```
$scope.timeFormattedList = $scope.timeList.map(function(value){
  var match = value.text.match(/(\d+):(\d+)\s*(\w+)/);
  var nvalue = {
    'text': value.text,
    'unique': (match[3] == 'pm' ? parseInt(match[1]) + 12 : match[1]) + "." + match[2],
    'value': value.value
  };
  return nvalue
});
```

[plunker code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxUN6WM9D7VNbUZpYxAS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var timeList =  [
      {
        "text": " 4:00 am",
        "value": "17"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:15 am",
        "value": "18"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:30 am",
        "value": "19"
      },
      {
        "text": " 3:45 pm",
        "value": "64"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:00 pm",
        "value": "65"
      },
      {
        "text": " 4:15 pm",
        "value": "66"
      }
    ];
timeList.forEach(function(obj) {
  var m = obj.text.match(/ ([0-9]+):([0-9]+) (.+)/);
  console.log(m[3]);
  if (m[3] == 'pm') {
    m[1] = +m[1]+12;
  }
  obj.unique = m[1] + "." + m[2];
});
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(timeList);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```